# Adding filter parameter to stream filter when using php://filter

Tags: php, stream, filtering

I have a binary that I want to convert to standard MIME-compliant base64 string. I thought I could use the [`php://filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) method to filter the stream, but I'm getting hung up on how to set the "line-length" parameter. There are other methods that would achieve similar results, but I'm trying to figure out if:

1. If it's even possible/allowed to set parameters for stream filters using the URI-style method.
2. How it is done, if it is possible.

Here are the pieces to the puzzle I've got so far:

Obviously, I could stop trying to be fancy and simply go with:

```
$binary = "path/to/binary.file";
$mime = file_get_contents($binary);
$mime = base64_encode($mime);
$mime = chunk_split($mime);
```

Or, I can use the `php://filter` method without the `line-length` parameter and split it afterward:

```
$binary = "path/to/binary.file";
$mime = file_get_contents("php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource=$binary");
$mime = chunk_split($mime);
```

Or, I can use `fopen` combined with `stream_filter_append` and not use the URL-style at all (as documented in the [Conversion Filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filters.convert.php) manual):

```
$binary = "path/to/binary.file";
$param = array('line-length' => 76, 'line-break-chars' => "\r\n");
$fp = fopen($binary, 'r');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.base64-encode',null, $param);
$mime = fread($fp, filesize($binary));
fclose($fp);
```

So all of the above give the same result, but none of them are what I was hoping for, which was to add the `line-length` parameter in the same URL for the stream. Something maybe like:

```
$mime = file_get_contents("php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode:line-length=76/resource=$binary");
```

I imagine the issue is that the parameter has to be passed as an array when `stream_filter_append` is used.

So does anyone know if what I want can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. If it's even possible/allowed to set parameters for stream filters using the URI-style method.

Unfortunately, currently, it is not possible<sup>1</sup> to provide anything other than the filter name (in your case `convert.base64-encode`) for those `php://filter` URLs.

I would go with your `stream_filter_append` approach, substituting `stream_get_contents` for `fread(...)`.

1. See the [current source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/php_fopen_wrapper.c?revision=296679&view=markup#l133) which explicitly uses `NULL` for the `filterparams` parameter to `php_stream_filter_create`. It wouldn't<sup>2</sup> be too much work to implement reading of arguments of the style you suggested.
2. I am not a C programmer.

Comment: Wow. Just what I needed to know. I am also NOT a C programmer, but in my case I wouldn't have even known what to look for or read it, so you're closer than I am. Thank!